# How can I get the localized date units?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I need a array with date units, for example Year,Month,Day....
I want them to be localized, for example in german it would be Jahr, Monat, Tag ...

It seems I can only get the localized string from date but not the units.
Is there a way to get those units from current calendar directly instead of translating them by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you will need to provide your own translations for those units. You can get the names of the days and months with NSDateFormatter but not the units themselves. How the unit is translated depends on grammatical case and number, so the translation is context sensitive. Don't forget, some languages have [grammatical numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Types_of_number) other than just singular and plural!

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"]];
    NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [timeZoneComps setHour:16];
    //specify whatever day, month, and year is appropriate
    NSDate *date=[gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(mymonth-1)];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
   NSString *weekName = [ df stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"The Week Name :: %@",weekName);
    [df release];
```

You can use above code and particularly `timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"` represents the abbreviation of various timezones like CDT, GMT,UTC,CST. I think it will be helpful to you.